# CODI + WELD: Specializing bean must extend another bean

Tags: cdi, jboss-weld, codi

I have a EE application, that uses JSF 2.0 (impl Mojarra 2.1.6). The server I use is glassfish 3.1.2, and CDI implementation is WELD. Sometimes when I run the application I get the following exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000047 Specializing bean must extend another bean:  Managed Bean [class org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.Jsf2ModuleStartupObserver] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.specialize(ManagedBean.java:458)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractBean.initialize(AbstractBean.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.initialize(AbstractClassBean.java:190)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.initialize(ManagedBean.java:322)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploy(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deployBeans(BeanDeployment.java:204)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:179)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:277)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

It doesn't happen always; and when it happens, if I run the application again, it works ok. But it's annoying, and I wonder why it's happening. does anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve all my issues with Glassfish3 by following the common pitfall hints in http://os890.blogspot.co.at/2012/05/slides-myfaces-codi-and-seam3-become.html (slide #32+)

Comment: thanks. It doesn't say anything about this specific error. I'll update weld version as suggested in the ppt, and see it that works

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in the Glassfish CDI integration. I'd suggest adding a ticket to their JIRA.